# Category tree in sinatra and activerecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm trying to make an online store using sinatra and activereord (using the `sinatra-activerecord` gem), and I'm having a little trouble getting my head around how to generate a 'tree' of categories (subcategories and stuff).

The categories database contains just the category name and the parent_id, and the activrecord model is as follows:

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_presence_of :name
   validates_uniqueness_of :name

   has_many :sub_categories, :class_name => 'Category',
     :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
   belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => 'Category'
 end
```

How would I go about making that something i can just have in templates as nested ul tags (i'm using haml if it makes a difference)?

Sorry for asking so much but I have never really worked with these sort of data structures.

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: `@sub = Category.find(...).sub_categories` and in the template iterate over `@sub` to display each sub-category. I'm not quite sure since I'm not using ActiveRecord

Comment: @daddz: I was going to do that, but that limits it to a finite amount of sub-categories. I'd rather have it so it doesn't matter how many categories (i think that means I want a recursive sort of thing, but I'm not sure)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more clever to just list the sub-categories of the current "selected" category? I suppose the higher your category depth is the longer a request will take since it has to iterate through all sub categories every time.

Comment: I'm going for a full nested ul tree menu type thing. There is javascript accordion type things to hide submenus and stuff. I think I  may have found a way to do what I want with a haml helper though... we'll see how I go

Comment: I figured it out! I'll post it as soon as Stack Overflow allows me to

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It uses a HAML helper and also applies the `current` class to the right element if `current_page` exists. Here's the helper

```
module Haml::Helpers
  def categories_menu(parent=nil, current_page=false)
    categories = Category.where(:parent_id => parent)
    haml_tag :ul do
      categories.each do |category|
        haml_tag :li, :class => ("current" if current_page == category.id) do
          haml_tag :a, :href => "/category/#{category.id}", :class => ("submenu" unless category.sub_categories.empty?) do
            haml_concat(category.name)
          end
          unless category.sub_categories.empty?
            categories_menu(category.id)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and you use it in a haml template as follows:

```
#test
    - categories_menu(nil, (@category.id if defined? @category))
```

No guarantees it'll work with anyone else's apps.